Enable Downloads on WordPress Attachment Page
I'm currently working on a WordPress site and need some help with enabling downloads for video attachments on their respective attachment pages. Since the videos are being handled in bulk, I'm using attachment pages to manage them automatically instead of creating individual pages.
Here’s what I’m trying to achieve:
When a user visits an attachment page (the page that displays individual media files such as videos), I want to provide a download link or button that allows them to directly download the video file. Right now, the attachment page only displays the video, but there’s no clear way for users to download it.
Here are some specifics about my setup:
I'm using the latest version of WordPress.
My theme is Bridge by Qode.
The videos are hosted directly on my WordPress site.
I need a solution that can be applied to all attachment pages automatically, as managing this manually for each video is not feasible.
I don’t have any specific plugins for managing downloads, but I'm open to suggestions if a plugin can handle this.
I’ve considered editing the attachment.php file, but I'm unsure of the best approach to ensure that all video attachment pages include a download link or button.
Has anyone tackled this before or can suggest a bulk method to achieve this? Any guidance or examples of code that I could use would be greatly appreciated!
